# Finding character which is not in double quote using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am new in writing regular expression and I have the following Scenario.

I have a string, like :

```
  string line = "if (true){var data = string.Format(\"something {0} {1}.\", \"is\", \"wrong\");}";
```

now I need to write a regular expression that just pick the closing curly braces which are not in the double quote

so far I tried this:

```
    "(^(\"[^\"]*\")(}))+"
```

- ^(\"[^\"]*\") : I want to Ignore any substring which is inside double quote, AND
- (}) : I want to take }
- +: for at least 1 occurrence.

But it seems I Did something wrong. Could any one please guide me to sort out where I did the wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What if `line` is something like `if(true /*{*/) { /*}*/ DoSomething() /*... more stuff*/ }`? Unless you're _very_, _very_ sure that your input is fixed, Regex is not the right tool for this kind of work.

Comment: I need to find all the closing curly braces ( } ) that are not bounded in double quotes, regardless their position

Comment: Find and do what? It is important. Split? Or replace with something?

Comment: So what about `if(true /*"{*/ ) { var s="{" + /* "} */ + ";"; { DoSomething() /* } */ }` (notice no closing `}` on this line (maybe on the next line)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Regex is not an appropriate technology for this kind of parsing. You'll probably need to write your own parser.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to read popular regex question about matching pairs of tags with regex - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. Make sure to read first 10-15 answers as some have useful guidance.

Comment: this question is not about matching pairs. the string might like " \"e e\" e" I need to find the "e" which is not in double quotes

Comment: @cuteteddy You should update your question with what you actually try doing then. A C-like language cannot be reliably parsed with a regular expression, unless you're looking for an extremely narrow case (and even then, it's possible that it can break down). It's usually much easier to write a parser (unless there's already one for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @cuteteddy you should clearly specify what you are looking for. The sample string you've posted looks like C# code, which is clearly not good example. Valid C# code can have unbalanced quotes - so good clar sample would clarify your post. (Same applies to showing HTML as sample - RegEx is generally wrong tool for parsing that too).

Comment: @cuteteddy You need to define what it mean that `e` is not in double quotes. Is this in double quotes: `/* "e" */ var a = e;` ?

Comment: @cuteteddy Ok, then what about this: `var a = '\"' + e + '\"';`  If you're trying to parse a source file of a C-like language, it's not possible with regex. If you're trying to do something else, update your question because at this time it's unclear then.

Comment: @cuteteddy: Just use `}(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)` then (or `}(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*(?:\\.[^"]*)*")*$)`). Does it work? (It should not, but you want to match `}` outside of quotes, then who knows...)

Comment: yes it works. thanks a lot

Comment: The first one or the second one? Depending on the answer, I will post an answer, or close the question as duplicate.

Comment: the first one works for me

Answer (score 0):

You just need these parts of your regex:

```
(?:\"[^\"]*\")|(})
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/wW0xN8/2)

Comment: Your regex appears to be picking out the strings, not the curly braces that the OP asked for.

Comment: Let's say straight: it won't do the job correctly. If I do not downvote, someone might do it. Please fix.

Comment: Unlikely to work correctly as OP seem to want to find braces only in actual code (excluding strings with all possible escapings and possibly comments - single/multiline as not specified otherwise). Expecting some ridiculous construct with `(?<..` to match strings and comments.